# Creating a UID inside Laravel 5, how can I enhance it to drop the probability of collision?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Currently I am creating a UID for my data inside a controller method called `randomId`. I've pasted the entire method below:

```
public static function randomId()
{

    $id = str_random(12);

    $validator = Validator::make(
        ['calculation_uid'=>$id],
        ['calculation_uid'=>'unique:calculations,calculation_uid']
    );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->randomId();
    }

    return strtoupper($id);
}
```

Basically generates a 12 digit alpha-numeric code, and then that gets run through the validator to ensure it doesn't already exist; if it does exist it runs the method again.

I know I can reduce the probability of collision by increasing it to say 16 chars but I'll forever be increasing it if I ever hit the limit.

Is there a way I can (for a lack of better phrasing) make this more unique? Or is my implementation likely to be okay?

Comment: This should work ok for a long time, but as time progresses it will become more likely to get collisions. Maybe using [Uniqueid](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_uniqid.asp) will be a better approach. Add some random chars as a suffix to make it even better.

Comment: Other than increasing the length of your string, another way to reduce the probability of collisions would be to increase the range of your *alphabet*, that is, to allow a greater set of characters. The number of combinations allowed will be `<number_of_allowed_characters>^<length_of_string>`. Additionally, you could look to make the column you're storing in the database case-sensitive, which would increase your character range again.

Comment: @MaartenPeels that's not a bad shout at all, I might look into that especially with the suffix.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? Just use a UUID https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier There are plenty of implementations out there

Comment: @Jonathon another good idea. Currently it's a-z & 0-9 so 36 chars and 12 is the length of the string

Comment: @Pevara mainly because this is used in a URI to read a stored calculation, i.e - website.dev/calculation/ABCD1234EF56

Comment: That being said, 36^12 (4.738381338×10¹⁸) combinations is a hell of a lot. The chance of a collision is going to be very small, but that depends on the amount of data you're storing.

Comment: @Jonathon yeah that's why I opted for these choices. Readable to the user and I *hoped* the chance of collision would be pretty low. The amount of data / calculations per minute is going to be quite low to be honest. Honestly probably a maximum of 200 per day

Comment: In which case, your current implementation is likely to be more than sufficient. The chance you would end up with a collision would be so low it's almost not worth considering. Your code does check for collisions which is the main thing, but in the real world, it's almost always only going to be running once for each of your calculations.

Comment: @Jonathon okay excellent. Thanks for your help and input. I'll stick with what I have :)

Comment: In that case, I would just stick with a standard auto increment id, but use a hash id when you send it to the frontend or use it in a url. http://hashids.org/ They just get longer as the need arises. There is a Laravel package available https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids