# Count possible unique values of a random password generator

Tags: php

I'm trying to create random password, this way:

```
function givemepass() {
    $pass = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $abc = str_shuffle("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");
        $x = mt_rand(0, 35);
        $pass .= substr($abc, $x, 1);
    }
    return $pass;
}
```

I'm interesting in how much unique values of `$pass` is possible using the above code.

I don't need the list of all values, just count.

Any idea?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'll probably benefit from the logic in the comments of a question I asked here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692766/creating-a-uid-inside-laravel-5-how-can-i-enhance-it-to-drop-the-probability-of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're generating a password with 4 character where each character has 36 possibilities. That makes 36 ^ 4 or 1.679.616 possibilities.

In addition, I want to note that `mt_rand` is not a secure way to generate passwords:

> This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using random_int(), random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.

Many random generators, like `mt_rand`, generate predictable random numbers (that's also why they call them pseudorandom number generators or PRNG), which means, if one can get a few passwords in a row, they could calculate all next and all previous passwords that where assigned to other users. The fact that you additionally call `str_shuffle` makes it a little harder, but still...

Comment: I think the last sentence may be overstating the vulnerability of `mt_rand` (suggesting that given only one single output, you can figure out all previous and subsequent outputs).

Comment: but `mt_rand` is just a tool here for randomize sequence of shuffled string. This cannot be predicted, I suppose.

Comment: `str_shuffle` is also based on the same Mersenne Twister PRNG, so again predictable, but because you're combining the two makes it little harder to reverse engineer. But if one can get a few passwords in a row, the rest can be calculated.

Comment: So if `mt_rand` is predictible, if `shuffle` is predictible - what is `unpredictible`?

Comment: @BeetleJuice in this case it's a combination of `mt_rand` and `str_shuffle`, but f.e. in your answer, using only `mt_rand`, each password gets 4 random numbers generated directly by `mt_rand` in sequence.

Comment: @bonaca [random_bytes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) or [random_int()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) f.e.

Answer (score 2):

Each character can be 1 of 36 possibilities.  For each of those characters, the next character can be 1 of 36 possibilities...

So the total number of possibilities with a 4 character password is `36 * 36 * 36 * 36`

You could simplify your code thus:

```
$chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$pass = '';
foreach(range(1,4) as $i) $pass .= $chars[mt_rand(0,35)];
```

Your code will run faster because you won't be shuffling the chars every time.

[**Live demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d2c5f8118e9702ec0af85d24e3be76123a820ee)

PS: This works for a simple application. However, if you need a cryptographically secure algorithm, don't use `md_rand`, and don't limit a password to 4 characters!

Comment: ...and don't limit it to only contain alphanumeric characters.